# In PROC LOGISTIC which value of the parameter is modelled?

Tags: sas, logistic-regression

My colleague and I are running exactly the same SAS PROC LOGISTIC, but with different input files.
SAS models ooX = 1 when I do it, and ooX = 0  when he does it.
We've checked record counts and FREQ counts for the main variables. They are the same.
Type 3 analysis of effects are the same. MLE estimates are the same, except for the intercept.
Does SAS require input to be sorted a certain way?

```
PROC LOGISTIC data = TTTT;
class ooX Y1 Y2 Y3 Y4;
model ooX = Y1 Y2 Y3 q1 q2 q3;
RUN;
```

Comment: SAS by default models event=first.  Are you sure your code and data are the exact same? You can both import your files to a common location and run proc compare on the datasets to verify they are the same.

Answer (score 1):

If your data are not sorted you can specify the order of your outcome variable right after calling `PROC LOGISTIC`.

I don't have the data, but assuming that ooX is a binary outcome variable with levels 0 and 1, the model will default to modeling ooX = 0 unless you specify that you want it in descending order.

```
PROC LOGISTIC data = TTTT descending; /* will model ooX = 1 */
class ooX Y1 Y2 Y3 Y4; /* Not sure if it makes sense to  have your outcome in the class statement */
model ooX = Y1 Y2 Y3 q1 q2 q3;
RUN;
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained in SAS manual (http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63347/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_logistic_sect030.htm)

> For binary response data with event and nonevent categories, if your event category has a higher Ordered Value, then by default the nonevent is modeled.